# Add Buttons to my CustomLayout i.e. TouchEventView without XML file

Tags: android, button, android-custom-view, android-button

```
public class TouchEventView extends View {

    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Path path = new Path();
    private ViewGroup viewGroup;
    public TouchEventView(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx);

        Button yourButton = new ImageButton(this);
        TouchEventView.addView(yourButton);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5 f);
        this.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float xPos = event.getX();
        float yPos = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                path.moveTo(xPos, yPos);
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                path.lineTo(xPos, yPos);
            break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what you have tried and what specific problems you have encountered. Since `TouchEventView` is not a `ViewGroup`, it cannot readily contain other widgets.

Comment: Basically `TouchEventView` is a drawing class and since it's not a `ViewGroup`       `Button button = new ImageButton(this);
 

 TouchEventView.addView(yourButton);`   is NOT WORKING.

Comment: Correct. You would have to convert `TouchEventView` to a `ViewGroup` and handle measuring and laying out the children yourself. Or, you could have `TouchEventView` extend an existing concrete layout manager (e.g., `LinearLayout`), so it can handle the children for you.

Comment: Thanks man! Great Help. @CommonsWare

Comment: @CommonsWare Dude i've tried extending LinearLayout but still button not working.I think the error maybe in these code lines `ViewGroup touch=new TouchEventView(ctx);    
             Button bt = new Button(ctx);    
             bt.setText("A Button");
             bt.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
             touch.addView(bt);`'